# How to get components of a JPanel which inside another JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel(first JPanel) and it fill with another JPanel(second JPanel).

I add this second JPanel to first JPanel programmatically. Like below,

```
firstJPanel.removeAll();
JPanel secondJPanel = new JPanel(gridLayout);
secondJPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Testing"));
secondJPanel.setName("secondJPanel");
firstJPanel.add(secondJPanel);
firstJPanel.revalidate();
```

The second JPanel has some components like JTextFields , JCheckBoxes, etc . I try to get these components . But I could get only the second JPanel.

Here is my code sample,

```
Component[] components = firstJPanel.getComponents();
for(int i=0;i<components.length;i++){
     System.out.println("Componenet name - " + components[i].getName());           
}
```

Have any iedas to get the components inside the second JPanel.

Best Regards.

Comment: secondJPanel.getComponents() ?

Comment: @javy :- There are lots of JPanels inside the first JPanel . That's why I use a loop to get all JPanels inside the first JPanel .

Comment: @javy :- So your suggestion is not working for me .

Comment: in your loop at some point `components[i]` will be your secondJPanel right? using that can't you get it's components ?

Comment: @javy :- explain your idea please

Comment: like the posted answer ,  use `components[i].getName().equals("nameOfJpanelTwo")` to identify the second JPanel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103160/discussion-between-javy-and-barrier).

Comment: Really short answer, don't.  Instead, create a custom class which contains the fields you need and provide accessors/mutators to get/set the values, that, or put the fields into some kind of `List` or `Map`

Comment: @MadProgrammer :- Thanks for the idea .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like

```
Component[] components = firstJPanel.getComponents();
for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Componenet name - " + components[i].getName());
    if (components[i] instanceof JPanel
            && components[i].equals(secondJPanel)) {

        Component s[] = ((JPanel) components[i]).getComponents();
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Sub Componenet name - " + s[j].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A loop to find the component that equals `secondJPanel`... while you already have a reference to `secondJPanel`. That doesn't strike you as superfluous?

Comment: @TT., It is just an example, here can be  `getName().equals()`. Generally this approach is itself superfluous.